# Different background colored nodes in Bootstrap Treeview

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

> Bootstrap Treeview (https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview)

I'm using Bootstrap treeview to create a contact management system. 
There are two types of contacts : Personal and Work and I'm displaying both the types in one tree.

Is there any way that I can show the two different types in two different colors on load of the tree?

As in Personal Contacts(Nodes)would have Blue Background and Work Contacts(Nodes) would have a White/Grey Background.

```
 $.ajax({
            "type": "POST",
            "url":Some Url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#tree').treeview({
                    data: data,
                    levels: 1,
                    backColor:"#FFFFFF",
                    onNodeSelected: function(event, data) {
                        Do Something.
                    }

                });
            }
        });
```

> backColor:"#FFFFFF"
>   This variable explicitly sets a color.

A basic demo of how the tree would look: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pranjali_pai21/854zsLLh/)

Answer (score 3):

So after doing some research I realized that this problem cannot be solved on the front-end  perspective. So I went into the bootstrap-treeview.js file and found a function that overrides the color( Line:622).

[image]

So to override the background color, it has to be done at the back end.In the nodes you will have another element/variable along with text and other variables, called the ***BackColor*** and set a color.

So in this sense I set a Color for my Personal contacts and I set a color for my Work contacts, to differentiate in the same tree.

Example:

```
 var myTree = [{
  text: "Parent1",
  backColor:"#FFAEAE",
  nodes: [{
    text: "Child11",
    nodes: [{
      text: "GrandChild111"
    }, {
      text: "GrandChild112"
    }]
  }, {
    text: "Child12"
  }]
}, {
  text: "Parent2",
  backColor:"#FFAEAE",
  nodes: [{
    text: "Child21"
  }, {
    text: "Child22"
  }]
}, {
  text: "Parent3",
  backColor:"#FFAEAE",
  nodes: [{
    text: "Child31"
  }, {
    text: "Child32"
  }, {
    text: "Child33"
  }]
}, {
  text: "Parent4",
  backColor:"#FFAEAE"
}, {
  text: "Parent5",
  backColor:"#FFAEAE",
  nodes: [{
    text: "Child51"
  }, {
    text: "Child52"
  }, {
    text: "Child33"
  }]
}, {
  text: "Parent6",
  backColor:"#56BAEC"
}, {
  text: "Parent7",
  backColor:"#56BAEC",
  nodes: [{
    text: "Child71",
    nodes: [{
      text: "GrandChild711"
    }, {
      text: "GrandChild712"
    }]
  }, {
    text: "Child72",
    nodes: [{
      text: "GrandChild711"
    }, {
      text: "GrandChild712"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  text: "Parent8",
  backColor:"#56BAEC"
}, {
  text: "Parent9",
  backColor:"#56BAEC",
  nodes: [{
    text: "Child91"
  }, {
    text: "Child92"
  }]
}, {
  text: "Parent10",
  backColor:"#56BAEC",
}];
```

Output:

[image]